# codeigniter handle code when application controller directory get accessed

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure, access-control

My directory settings

```
-- application 
   -- controllers 
      -- admin 
         -- manage
```

When I accessed 'localhost/admin', it redirect to 'localhost/'. 
Question is : 
- Where should I handle this ? I want to do something when someone accessed 'localhost/admin' , not just redirect them to 'localhost/'.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's a three part answer.

You need a controller named (in this example) `example.php`.  You need a view in your view folder called `example_view.php`.  And you need to edit your config/routes file.

First, create a controller in your admin folder.  In this case I'll call it example.php.  It should look like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example extends CI_Controller {

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| CLASS CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
*/    
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    } 
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| VIEW FOR INDEX LAUNCHING PAGE
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
*/   
public function index() {
        $this->load->view('example_view');
}


}//end controller class

/* End of file example.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/admin/example.php */
```

Second create a view called `example_view.php` and put it in your view folder.

Third open `config/routes.php` and add this line:
    `$route['admin'] = "admin/example";`

This last part points anything that is called `localhost/admin` to the view indicated in your `example.php` `index()` function.

Comment: Or just do step 3 if you want localhost/admin to redirect to localhost/admin/manage (change example to manage)

Comment: Yeah, David, I'm new here so I'm not exactly sure how much info to provide, yet.  Your answer is dead-on, though.

Comment: Thx very much. The third part is what I'm looking for. ~~